# Laravel Open_basedir being spammed in logs, but open_basedir is disabled

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, composer-php, open-basedir

Recently after I restarted my server I started receiving a php open_basedir restriction being spammed in my Laravel.log every minute. I disabled open_basedir following this error to try to debug it but it is still being spammed. It appears to be coming from a Symfony file called PhpExecutableFinder.php line (44), on that line there is a is_file(PHP_BINARY). Also to note is that my composer has also started having open_basedir problems as well. Bellow is the detailed error pulled from Laravel.log

```
[2015-11-22 18:39:05] local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 
'is_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect. 
File(C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP56\php.exe) 
is not within the allowed path(s): 
(C:/Inetpub/vhosts/**************.com\;C:\Windows\Temp\)' in 
C:\inetpub\vhosts\***************.com\httpdocs\vendor\symfony\process\PhpExecutableFinder.php:44
```

I've been working to resolve this for the past few days and was hoping someone might have some insight into why this is occurring.

Comment: looks like it can't write into your Temp folder. Are there any restrictions? If you run `phpinfo()` what is in `open_basedir`?

Comment: The value is None. I disabled it to try to troubleshoot this. I still can't find a solution and its been almost a week, it's very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in cases like this, something like CPanel can have settings for open_basedir (perhaps named differently) that can override whatever is in your php.ini file.  Not sure if this is what happened in your case, but would be interested to hear if you ever figured it out.